# How to display the text on the video with Pygame and Opencv on Google Collab?

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, google-colaboratory, video-editing

I'm trying to display a text on a video with Pygame and OpenCV on Google Collab, but the text isn't displayed on the output. The output file still the same as the original video. In the OpenCV view (`cv2_imshow(frame_with_text)`) the text also cannot be seen.

```py
import pygame
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Upload video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join('sample_data', 'BACKGROUND.mp4'))

# Get video information
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = 30 #cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frames_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
duration = frames_count / fps

# Export video
directory = r'sample_data'
output_file = os.path.join(directory, f'teste.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/content/drive/MyDrive/teste.mp4', fourcc, fps, (width, height))

# Create a pygame suface with the same dimention as the video
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def edit():
  while cap.isOpened():
      ret, frame = cap.read()

      if not ret:
          break
      
      font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
      text = "This is a test"
      pista_surface = font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255))
      screen.blit(pista_surface, (94, 479))
      # Actual time in seconds
      current_time = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) / fps

      # Convert OpenCV frame to a pygame surface
      pygame_frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame.swapaxes(0, 1))

      # Update Pygame screen
      pygame.display.flip()

      # Convert Pygame surface to a OpenCV frame
      frame_with_text = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame_frame).swapaxes(0, 1)

      # Save frame to the output
      out.write(frame_with_text)

      # Visualize frame 
      cv2_imshow(frame_with_text)

      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

      # Set the same FPS as the original video
      clock.tick(fps)

      # Verify if the end of the video was reached
      if current_time >= frames_count:
        break

  cap.release()
  out.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()


edit()
```

I tried moviepy but I got the image magic error on Goggle Collab, therefore I'm using pygame this way.I have tried to install image magic, but all the solutions I have found didn't worked.

Comment: google colab can't show GUIs to you. do not use `waitKey()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must draw the text on the surface that is written to the output and you need to `blit` that surface on the Pygame screen

```py
def edit():
    while cap.isOpened():
        # [...]

        # Convert OpenCV frame to a pygame surface
        pygame_frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame.swapaxes(0, 1))

        # blit text on surface
        pygame_frame.blit(pista_surface, (94, 479))

        # blit surface on Pygame screen
        screen.blit(pygame_frame, (0, 0))

        # Update Pygame screen
        pygame.display.flip()

        # Convert Pygame surface to a OpenCV frame
        frame_with_text = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame_frame).swapaxes(0, 1)

        # Save frame to the output
        out.write(frame_with_text)

        # [...]
```